# VF page with 2 search conditions

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I want to create vf search page with 2 search conditions.

In Account object Type and Industry are 2 picklists. Based on these 2 fields I have to search and display records but I'm getting error when click on search records-- **Formula Expression is required on the action attributes**

Please help me with the right code if possible. Thank You

**Controller**

```
public list <Account> acc {get;set;}
public String searchKey1 {get;set;}
 public String searchKey2 {get;set;}
public Searchwith2value( ) {
}
public void search(){
    string searchquery='select Name, id from account where Rating IN:searchkey1 AND Industry IN:searchKey2 Limit 5';
    acc= Database.query(searchquery);
}
public void clear(){
    acc.clear();
}
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page Controller="Searchwith2value">
   <apex:form>
       <apex:inputText value="{!searchKey1}" label="Input"/>
       <apex:inputText value="{!searchKey2}" label="Input"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!searchKey1} AND {!searchKey2} "/> <!-- -->
       <apex:commandButton value="Clear records" action="{!clear}"/>
       <apex:pageBlock title="Search Result">
           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
               <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockTable>
       </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image: VF page output]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `action` attribute should be the Apex controller method you wish to call. Here,

```
<apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!searchKey1} AND {!searchKey2} "/> <!-- -->
```

should be

```
<apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!search}"/> <!-- -->
```

Consuming the values of the input elements is the responsibility of the Apex controller. You don't need to reference them in the `action` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @David_Reed, for your suggestion.